# Error While deploying Big Object

Tags: big-object

[image: Error while deploying big object]

When deploying big object, Im getting the error, says, no package.xml found. but I have included in the package.[image: If we extract the package, It looks like this.]

Why does my deployment fail? I am using force.com workbench to deploy. Using my developed org. Both my file and dev org in same version 41.0

Comment: Please share your configuration of the deployment. This type of error message tends to indicate you did not select the `Single Package` deployment option.

Comment: I have selected 'single package' and 'check' deployment option in workbench while deploying.

Answer (score 2):

This issue happens if you are zipping files in MAC .

As per the post [here](https://medium.com/@wangyidan621/salesforce-workbench-zip-deployment-no-package-xml-found-error-on-mac-ec7ce49a7126) the issue is because MAC during file compression adds some hidden folders and files that workbench is incompatible with .

The Resolution
Remove those files! There are many ways to do that. What author suggests is to use  he Terminal command line. Cd into the folder to be zipped, then run below

```
zip -r -X YourZipFileName.zip *
```

Answer (score -1):

Click on Check only and single package checkbox first and test this before deploying. And on the second run, deploy it directly post testing.